Can't use sudo anymore since running chmod: sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
Before I start, I am no Linux expert by any means, I just know the basics and am still at the beginning of my Linux/Server journey.
I messed up, I've used chmod before but now I used it in the root directory.
Since I couldn't see my directories as a root user (I'm pretty sure), I accessed root with
sudo su -
and then ran
chmod -R 777 /
in the root directory. Now every time I try to use sudo I get this:
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit

I tried looking up a solution, but since I can't use sudo everything seems to be useless.
What I tried:
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers >> Authentication failure
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers >> Authentication failure
Did I mess the whole system up now? I hope anyone can give me feedback, and hopefully tell me that my mess can be fixed

You messed up your system. There might be ways to fix this but they would be complicated and time consuming and there might still be leftovers from your action which surprise you later. Best ist to either restore from backup or reinstall. Learn from this lesson and don't play aruond with permissions of system files if you don't know what you're doing.

Thanks for your answer! I mounted my 12TB drive to /mnt/nasdrive/. Meaning all my files are on a mounted drive. Can I just reset the system by resetting the 128gb drive and not touch the mounted drive?

Yes, you can, but: we don't know your hardware configuraiton, is this 12TB drive on the same machine or on the on a different machine on your local network, so hard to give correct advice about where you need to be careful. You shouldn't ask follow-up questions in comments, instead open a new question with sufficient details, that's the best way to get helpful answers. AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a forum. Thanks for understanding.

Sorry didn't know, I will open a new question, thank you!
